# Vertical Divider not showing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to use the `VerticalDivider` widget to separate items in the `Row`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/buraktabn/18b4468307f4de22ef6eec399c6f1231) is the whole body.

[image]

**Row:**

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('420 Posts', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff666666)),),
    VerticalDivider(
      thickness: 2,
      width: 20,
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    Text('420 Posts', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff666666)),)
  ],
),
```

Comment: I test and it's showing fine.

Comment: show your whole widget or some parents widgets.

Comment: I updated the question. You can see the whole body in the Github Gist.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Wrap your `Row` with `IntrinsicHeight`,

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('420 Posts', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff666666)),),
      VerticalDivider(
        thickness: 2,
        width: 20,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      Text('420 Posts', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff666666)),)
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: That's works. I wonder why we need to wrap with IntrinsicHeight.

Comment: I am not sure. It forces all the children in row to reasonable height.

Comment: And in the latest Flutter SDK (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5), the vertical divider actually tries to get the max height. So I am not getting the issue at all.

Comment: I'm using Flutter v1.15.17 and I also have to wrap in `IntrinsicHeight`.  The cross-axis sizing behavior of component widgets is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Working...can you explain why this is needed ?

Comment: It works but I'd rather just use container (instead of VerticalDivider) than add another wrapper widget..

Comment: IntrinsicHeight is expensive to build so be careful and only use when there is no other solutions. In this case simple container would work.
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html

Comment: Thanks Sangam, yes it is expensive, as it has the worst case as `O(N^2)` and thanks for the resource!

Answer (score 25):

The VerticalDivider need height for work correctly, use it with the SizedBox or equivalent with height param defined.

Example:

```
SizedBox(
   height: 40
   child: VerticalDivider(
      thickness: 2,
      width: 20,
      color: Colors.black,
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also wrap Row into Container with specified height.

Comment: Show full context

Comment: I gave fix height to SizedBox(), added vetrical divider as child, no output, same issue

Comment: Weird. Again, show full code to see what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

When you add Vertical Divider inside Row, Wrap widget, it may not display because of varying heights. The main reason, for this reason, is the unrestricted height of the parent widget of the Row/Wrap widget.
So use fixed height like a Container or IntrinsicHeight

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `row` with `IntrinsicHeight` or specify some height of your `row` widget

Example With **IntrinsicHeight** :

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    children: const [
      YourWidget1(),
      VerticalDivider(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      YourWidget2()
    ],
  ),
),
```

Example With **Fixed Height** :

```
SizedBox(
  height: 40,
  child: Row(
    children: const [
      YourWidget1(),
      VerticalDivider(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      YourWidget2()
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `VerticalDivider` with `SizedBox` and specify the height

This works:

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 200,
  child: VerticalDivider(
    width: 20,
    thickness: 1,
    color: Colors..teal
  ),
)
```

Comment: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)